# How to push image at the bottom of the present slide?

Tags: beamer, graphics, vertical-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Beamerposter… Columns not all aligned at top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51487/beamerposter-columns-not-all-aligned-at-top)

I have made two columns in a `beamer` presentation slide and both of them contain image.

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Vision(Information Processing)}
  \begin{block}{Measuring distance}
\begin{columns}
  \column[l]{0.65\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \scriptsize\item Equidistant vertical dots are drawn on screen
    \scriptsize\item Markers are placed on the ground to match them
    \scriptsize\item Distance is measured
    \scriptsize\item Interpolated graph is plotted
  \end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[b]
    \includegraphics<1->[width=\textwidth]{sdd-vis-distancegraph}
\end{figure}
  \column[r]{0.35\textwidth}
    \includegraphics<1->[width=\textwidth]{sdd-vis-distance}
\end{columns}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
```

And the output looks like this:

[image: output of above code]

As you can see, the image on the left is not aligned with the image on the right. If I can push the left image to the bottom, I think the alignment will be fine. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `\begin{columns}[b]` help?

Comment: perhaps i misunderstand, but the x-axes and their descriptions appear to be lined up nicely.  the two graphs aren't the same size in the y-direction, but (to my eyes) they would look misaligned if the strong horizontals were not in a straight line.  or do you mean "shift them both to the right", so that the left side is aligned with the beginning of the subheading?

Comment: @percusse: Your suggestion worked nicely! Now they are lined up :) Thank you!

barbara beeton: You are right, the two graphs are not lined up, and even when the images are aligned as I wanted them to be, the graphs will not line up with the other image nicely. I need to come up with better images for that.

Comment: I have voted to close this question since this issue has been answered in another question. Please let me know if you have any objections.