# Fix the height of a column

Tags: beamer, minipage, columns

I have several similar slides in `beamer`. Each slide has 2 parts side by side. On the left hand, there is a `tikzpicture` in a `minipage`, it is same for all the slides; On the right hand, there are several `blocks`, some slides have more blocks, some have less. What I notice is, due to the different length of the blocks of the different slides, the position of the left hand changes - This is not what I want. I would like the height of the left hand to remain for all the slides, which is independent of the length and height of the right hand. Does anyone know how to do it?

Here are 2 typical slides, one could notice that the position of the left rectangle is not same between the 2 slides...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xifthen}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.32\textwidth}
      \resizebox{0.66\textwidth}{!}{%  
        \begin{minipage}[t][10cm][t]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}% Remove fbox rule/sep width
          \hspace*{-1em}{\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale=0.4]
              \filldraw[fill=white!20] (2,2) rectangle (6,12);
            \end{tikzpicture}}
        \end{minipage}}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.64\textwidth}
      \begin{alertblock}
        a \vspace{2cm} b
      \end{alertblock}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.32\textwidth}
      \resizebox{0.66\textwidth}{!}{%  
        \begin{minipage}[t][10cm][t]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}% Remove fbox rule/sep width
          \hspace*{-1em}{\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale=0.4]
              \filldraw[fill=white!20] (2,2) rectangle (6,12);
            \end{tikzpicture}}
        \end{minipage}}
    \end{column}
     \begin{column}{0.64\textwidth}
      \begin{alertblock}
        a \vspace{7cm} b
      \end{alertblock}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a *complete* document illustrating the undesired bahaviour?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51487/beamerposter-columns-not-all-aligned-at-top

Comment: @percusse, the option `[T]` does not solve my problem, because the height of the left hand is still *dependent* to the height of the right hand - that is not what I want...

Comment: If you can give a complete code we can check otherwise there is not much to guess.

Comment: I have amended the OP with a complete example, I think maybe it is because the block in the second slide is too long for the left hand...

Comment: Please edit the question to be a complete example. That is: start `\documentclass` and end `\end{document}` so people can run the code and suggest changes as required.

Comment: It is better now...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve a consistent top alignment, if you set the optional parameters for both the `frame` and the `columns` environment:

```
\begin{frame}[t] % align frame content to top
  \begin{columns}[T] % align all columns to top of first line
    % definition of individual columns
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```